# Add input element to form dependent on other form element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

If `sonuc1` input is `NO` add another input element named `sonuc2` **BEFORE** submitting

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sonuc1').on('keyup', function() {
    var sonuc1 = $('#sonuc1').val();
    var csrf_value = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    
   
    // Send AJAX request to the Django view

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/pkl/rpa/', // Replace with the actual URL of your Django view
      data: {
        'sonuc1': sonuc1,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // Handle the response from the server if needed
        console.log('Server Response:', response);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="sonuc1" id="sonuc1" placeholder="1.Sonuç">
  <button type="submit">Ekle</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You want to send the sonuc1 to the server at all times or you want to do so only when submitting? Because now the form can be submitted too. Also what to do if the user writes NO and clicks submit?

Answer (score 0):

If you want another tag to be automatically added when the change entered in this tag is "NO", you can write a code like the following using javascript:

```html
<form id="form" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="sonuc1" id="sonuc1" placeholder="1.Sonuc" />
  <button type="submit">Ekle</button>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("sonuc1").addEventListener("change", function () {
    if (this.value.toUpperCase() === "NO") {
      var newInput = document.createElement("input");
      newInput.type = "text";
      newInput.name = "sonuc2";
      newInput.placeholder = "2.Sonuc";
      document
        .getElementById("form")
        .insertBefore(newInput, document.querySelector("button"));
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how can i integrate your code to my edited ajax code @Tahir1071a

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry, man. I'm also in the process of learning javascript, I thought that was the problem. I don't know how to use Ajax

Comment: no worries your answer is helpful to my solution